# What's it called when someone thinks something's cute?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

You know how right before going "Awwwww!" People breathe in? What exactly is that called? And if there's no specific word for it, how do I describe it?

Example: (This guy 's obsessed with this couple btw) I silently kiss Davin on the cheek, making him turn bright red.

Tj ____. "Aww! You two are so perfect!"

Comment: A recent coinage that might work for you is ***squee***. Mainstream dictionaries mostly link this to a *squealing sound* but it's often used figuratively for the feeling inspired when something is *so cute* and/or *so romantic*.

Comment: @WS2 It designates events which make half the perceivers *squee* and the other half *facepalm*.

Comment: Anime watchers (and Japanese speakers) will probably recognize "kawaii" ( 可愛い ). It is the romanized spelling of the Japanese word for "cute", but a little broader.  Anime characters exclaim it with great frequency.

Comment: 'cooing' might be close to what you are after

Comment: @WS2 It's a very common word that's been in the English language for a *long* time. Feel free to use any dictionary to look it up!

Comment: Are you asking what Part of Speech 'Awww!' is (interjection?), or a verb/adjective/noun to characterize the gasp/coo/whatever? Can a gasp/coo/whatever qualify as an interjection? only if you vocalize it? etc.

Answer (score 15):

The short intake of breath is called a [**gasp**](http://thefreedictionary.com/gasp). In that sentence, TJ gasped, "Aww! You two are so perfect!"

You could also say TJ was [**fawning**](http://thefreedictionary.com/fawning) over the cute couple.

Answer (score 4):

Though Cameron's suggestion of fawning is particularly good, this action could also be described as ***[gushing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gush)***:

> to make an effusive display of affection or enthusiasm
>
> *"Aww! You two are so perfect!" Tj **gushed***.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: This technically fits the blank, but doesn't address the actual question.